# Queue of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, queue

Hi I'm learning Swift coming from Java and in Java I'm used to initializing Queue's of Lists like this:

```
Queue<List<Integer>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

I have found this code to create the Queue data structure in Swift:

```
struct Queue<T> {
  private var elements: [T] = []

  mutating func enqueue(_ value: T) {
    elements.append(value)
  }

  mutating func dequeue() -> T? {
    guard !elements.isEmpty else { 
      return nil
    }
    return elements.removeFirst()
  }

  var head: T? {
    return elements.first
  }

  var tail: T? {
    return elements.last
  }
}
```

My only question is if it is possible to have a Queue of arrays and how could I initialize that?

Thanks

Comment: `Queue<[Int]>()`

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by the Apple Swift Packages `swift collections` and the type `Deque<Element>` where `Element` could be an array of something as mentionned.

The work in progress on `PriorityQueue` might be relevant as well.

Meantime @Joakim answer does the job:
`let queueOfIntArrays = Queue<[Int]>()`